# type mismatch error involving nested parentheses

Tags: scala

type mismatch

```
found   : ((A, (Long, Array[String], Int))) => A
required: (A, (Long, Array[String], Int)) => A
```

I don't understand this error I am trying to fold over a sequence where A is the state type. Why has it 'found' a nested tuple where I have provided something like:

`xs.foldLeft(zeroSt) {case (st,(a,b,c)) => st}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error where accumulator parameter of `foldLeft` is missing

```
xs.foldLeft(zeroSt) { case (acc, (st, (a, b, c))) => // accumulate in acc }
                             ^
                             |
                        this was missing
```

In other words, `B` was specified incorrectly in the signature of `foldLeft`

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
                           ^
                           |
                        this was incorrect
```

As a side note, I use the following mnemonic to remember where the accumulator fits:

- with fold*Left* the accumulator is the *"left"* element of the tuple
- with fold*Right* the accumulator is the *"right"* element of the tuple